# Convert 3D data into maya anim file

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, kinect, maya

I'm now working on collecting data from a kinect skeleton model which contains 23 3D-point/set at a time, and also I would like to convert them into .anim file so that I can load it into unity and make a character move.
Is there any solution to do so? To convert 3D data into .anim file?
P.S. I already have 3d-data stored in the format like [time|x|y|z].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Windows you can use [Brekel's tools](http://www.brekel.com/kinect-3d-scanner/) (have a look at this [workflow tutorial](http://area.autodesk.com/blogs/louis/3ds_max_and_motion_builder_workflow_and_a_bit_of_kinect))

If you can write a bit of code, you can also try [this approach](http://archdigital.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/just-for-fun-kinect-maya.html).

[image: kinect skeleton to maya using SimpleOpenNI and UDP]

Comment: I see, you don't need the data in Maya in general, just need to export to .anim format. I just had a look at the [.anim format](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/index.html?url=files/GUID-87541258-2463-497A-A3D7-3DEA4C852644.htm,topicNumber=d30e246535) and it reminds me a bit of .bvh. It shouldn't be to hard to write to .anim since it's plain text/ascii. At a first glance it looks like you need to define the bone hierarchy and convert your x,y,z positions to bone rotations. Unfortunately I can't help until the end of the month....

Comment: ...would using one of the methods above to load kinect data into Maya then exporting it to .anim format from maya work ? It's not automated, but perhaps it would help test and maybe script as a backup option ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing the second solution! That might helps a lot, okay I'll try to figure out the bone hierarchy and see if it works, thanks!